# Simple PHP MVC framework

Tags: php, mvc, pdo, controller

I recently wrote this PHP MVC framework. Would like your review.

index.php

```
<?php
//In the linked web folder we would only have index.php,js,css,images. 
//Rest of the code is in ../core
chdir('../core');
require 'common.inc.php'; //define constants, auto loading etc

run();


function run() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['module']) && isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
                $ctrl = getControllerFromModule();
                if($ctrl) {
                        $ctrl->run();
                } else {
                        HttpUtils::badRequest();
                }
        } else {
                HomeService::showHomepage();
        }
}

function getControllerFromModule() {
        $ctrl = null;
        $module = $_REQUEST['module'];
        switch($module) {
                case 'home':
                        $ctrl = new HomeController();
                        break;
                case 'browse':
                        $ctrl = new BrowseController();
                        break;
                case 'access':
                        $ctrl = new AccessController();
                        break;
                case 'singlePlace':
                        $ctrl = new SinglePlaceController();
                        break;
                case 'pg':
                        $ctrl = new PaymentGatewayController();
                        break;
                case 'auth':
                        $ctrl = new AuthController();
                        break;
                case 'static':
                        $ctrl = new StaticPageController();
                        break;
                case 'account':
                        $ctrl = new AccountController();
                        break;
        }
        return $ctrl;
}
```

BaseController.php

```
<?php

class BaseController {

        protected $GET_Map;
        protected $POST_Map;

        public function run() {
                $action = isset($_REQUEST['action'])?$_REQUEST['action']:null;
                $this->setMaps();
                $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
                if ($method == 'GET') {
                        $this->runGet($action);
                } else if ($method == 'POST') {
                        $this->runPost($action);
                }
        }

        protected function runGet($action) {
                $this->runMethod($action,$this->GET_Map);
        }

        protected function runPost($action) {
                $this->runMethod($action,$this->POST_Map);
        }

        protected function runMethod($action,$map) {
                if ($action && $map && isset($map[$action])) {
                        $func = $map[$action];
                        $func();
                } else {
                        $this->defaultAction();
                }
        }

        protected function setMaps() {
                $this->map = array();
        }

        protected function defaultAction() {
//can be overridden by subclass
                $module = $_REQUEST['module'];
                $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
                $msg = "No handler found for module = $module and action = $action";
                Log::error($msg);
                HttpUtils::badRequest();
        }

}
```

A sample Controller:(just set GET_map,POST_map)

```
<?php
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected function setMaps() {
        $this->GET_Map['showHome'] = function() {
            HomeService::showHome();
        };
        $this->POST_Map['changeHome'] = function() {
            HomeService::changeHome();
        };
    }

}
```

BaseEntity.php

```
<?php

class BaseEntity {
/*
Requirement for it to work correctly : 
1. MySql DB Column names are same as class member names.
2. All the member variables which are to be persisted, should be protected/public. Since get_class_vars() doesn't private members.
*/

    protected $id;
    protected $createdAt;
    protected $updatedAt;
    protected $createdBy;
    protected $updatedBy;
    protected $isActive;

    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy() {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy) {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;
    }

    public function getUpdatedBy() {
        return $this->updatedBy;
    }

    public function setUpdatedBy($updatedBy) {
        $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt) {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    public function __construct($id = '') {
        if ($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->buildFromDb();
        }
    }

    public function save() {
        if (!$this->id) {
            $this->createdAt = time();
            $this->updatedAt = $this->createdAt; 
            DBP::insert(static::getTableName(), $this->getFields());
            $this->id = DBP::getLastInsertId();
        } else {
            $this->updatedAt = time(); 
            DBP::update(static::getTableName(), $this->getFields(), $this->getId());
        }
    }

    public function delete() {
        DBP::delete(static::getTableName(), $this->getId());
    }

    public function buildFromDb($row = array()) {
        if (!$row) {
            $columnNames = $this->getCommaSeparatedColumnNames();
            $query = "select $columnNames from " . static::getTableName() . " where id = :id";
            $row = DBP::getSingleResult($query, array('id' => $this->id));
        }

        if ($row) {
            $this->fillThisWithDBValues($row);
        } else {
            $this->id = null;
        }
    }

    private function fillThisWithDBValues($row) {
        $fieldNames = static::getColumnNames();
        foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
            if (isset($row[$fieldName])) {
                $setterMethod = "set" . ucfirst($fieldName);
                $this->$setterMethod($row[$fieldName]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getAssocVersion() {
        $row = array();
        $fieldNames = static::getColumnNames();
        foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
            $getterMethod = "get" . ucfirst($fieldName);
            $row[$fieldName] = $this->$getterMethod();
        }
        return $row;
    }

    protected static function getTableName() {
        //object of this class can't be persisted
        return null;
    }



    protected static function getExistingColumns() {
        $cols = array();
        $query = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` as col FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=:db_name AND `TABLE_NAME`=:table_name";
        $bindings = array('db_name' => DB_NAME, 'table_name' => static::getTableName());
        $rows = DBP::getResultSet($query,$bindings);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $cols[] = $row['col'];
        }
        return $cols;
    }

    public function getFields() {
        /*
         * For get_class_vars to work correctly - 
         * all inheriting classes should have all those variables as protected which we want in getFields().
         */
        $fields = get_class_vars(get_called_class());
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $getterMethod = "get" . ucfirst($key);
            $fields[$key] = $this->$getterMethod();
        }
        if (isset($fields['id'])) {
            unset($fields['id']);
        }
        return $fields;
    }

    private static function getColumnNames() {
        return array_keys(get_class_vars(get_called_class()));
    }

    public static function getCommaSeparatedColumnNames() {
        return implode(",", static::getColumnNames());
    }

    protected static function getColumnDefinitions() {
        //Subclass should provide its column definitions
        return array();
    }

    private static function getDefaultDefs(){
        $defs = array();
        $defs['id'] = 'bigint(20) primary key auto_increment';
        $defs['createdAt'] = 'int(11) NOT NULL';
        $defs['updatedAt'] = 'int(11) NOT NULL';
        $defs['createdBy'] = 'varchar(64) default null';
        $defs['updatedBy'] = 'varchar(64) default null';
        $defs['isActive'] = 'int(11) default 1';
        return $defs;
    }

    public static function createOrUpdateTable() {
        $existingColumnNames = static::getExistingColumns();
        $update = false;
        if($existingColumnNames) {
            $update = true;
        }
        $defs = self::getDefaultDefs();
        $tableName = static::getTableName();
        $extraDefs = static::getColumnDefinitions();
        $finalDefs = array_merge($defs,$extraDefs);
        if(!$update) {
            $query = "create table $tableName (";
            foreach ($finalDefs as $col => $def) {
                $query .= "$col $def,";
            }
            $query = rtrim($query, ",");
            $query .= ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
            DBP::runQuery($query);
        } else {
            $newColumnDefs = array();
            foreach($finalDefs as $col => $def) {
                if (!in_array($col, $existingColumnNames)) {
                    $newColumnDefs[$col] = $def;
                }
            }
            $query = "alter table $tableName";
            foreach($newColumnDefs as $col => $def) {
                $query .= " add column $col $def,";
            }
            $query = rtrim($query,",");
            //echo $query;die;
            DBP::runQuery($query);
        }
    }

}
```

A sample Entity :
City.php

```
<?php
class City extends BaseEntity {
    protected $name;
    protected $lat;
    protected $lng;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getLat() {
        return $this->lat;
    }

    public function setLat($lat) {
        $this->lat = $lat;
    }

    public function getLng() {
        return $this->lng;
    }

    public function setLng($lng) {
        $this->lng = $lng;
    }

    protected static function getTableName() {
        return 'city';
    }

    protected static function getColumnDefinitions() {
        //only use of this method is for creating table programmatically
        $defs = array();
        $defs['name'] = 'varchar(64) default null';
        $defs['lat'] = 'double default null';
        $defs['lng'] = 'double default null';
        return $defs;
    }
}
```

DBP.php (The DB class, using PDO)

```
<?php

class DBP {

    private static $dbh;
    private static $sth;
    private static $logQueryExceptions = true;
    private static $slowQueryErrorLog = true;
    private static $dbHost = null;
    private static $dbName = null;
    private static $dbUser = null;
    private static $dbPass = null;

    public static function enableSlowQueryErrorLog() {
        self::$slowQueryErrorLog = true;
    }

    public static function disableSlowQueryErrorLog() {
        self::$slowQueryErrorLog = false;
    }

    public static function enableQueryExceptionLog() {
        self::$logQueryExceptions = true;
    }

    public static function disableQueryExceptionLog() {
        self::$logQueryExceptions = false;
    }

    public static function configure($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) {
        self::$dbHost = $db_host;
        self::$dbName = $db_name;
        self::$dbUser = $db_user;
        self::$dbPass = $db_pass;
        self::$dbh = null;
    }

    private static function init() {
        if (!self::isConfigured()) {
            self::configure(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS); //these are pre-defined constants. Defined elsewhere
        }
        try {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . self::$dbName . ';';
            self::$dbh = new PDO($dsn, self::$dbUser, self::$dbPass);
            self::$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$sth = null;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getResultSet($query, $bindings = array()) {
        self::runQuery($query, $bindings);
        return self::getRows();
    }

    public static function beginTransaction() {
        self::runQuery('start transaction');
    }

    public static function commit() {
        self::runQuery('commit');
    }

    public static function rollback() {
        self::runQuery('rollback');
    }

    public static function getPlaceHolderStringAndIdBindings(Array $arr, $prefix = 'id') {
        $placeHolderStr = '';
        $idBindings = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            $key = "$prefix$i";
            $placeHolderStr .= ":$key,";
            $idBindings[$key] = $arr[$i];
        }
        $placeHolderStr = rtrim($placeHolderStr, ",");
        return array($placeHolderStr, $idBindings);
    }

    public static function getCountFromQuery($query, Array $bindings = array()) {
        $query = "select count(1) as cnt from ($query)t";
        self::runQuery($query, $bindings);
        $rows = self::getRows();
        return $rows[0]['cnt'];
    }

    public static function getLastInsertId() {
        return self::$dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    private static function isConfigured() {
        return (self::$dbHost && self::$dbName && self::$dbUser);
    }

    public static function runQuery($query, $bindings = array(), $attempt = 0) {
        $maxAttempts = 2;
        if ($attempt < $maxAttempts) {
            try {
                if ((stripos($query, "select") !== 0) && (isset($_SESSION['viewOnly']))) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!self::$dbh) {
                    self::init();
                }
                $bt = microtime(true);
                if (!self::$dbh) {
                    throw new Exception('DBH is null');
                }
                self::$sth = self::$dbh->prepare($query);
                self::$sth->execute($bindings);
                $at = microtime(true);
                $diff = ($at - $bt);
                if ($diff > 2) {
                    if (self::$slowQueryErrorLog) {
                        Log::error("Time Taken : $diff seconds", $bindings, $query);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                if (self::$logQueryExceptions) {
                    Log::error($error, $bindings, $query);
                }
                if (($e->getCode() == 'HY000') && ($attempt < $maxAttempts)) { //MySql server has gone away and other General errors denoted by HY000
                    Log::error("Sleeping before attempting again to handle HY000 attempt = $attempt");
                    self::$dbh = null;
                    sleep(5);
                    self::runQuery($query, $bindings, $attempt + 1);
                } else {
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log::error("max attempts crossed. $query");
        }
    }

    public static function delete($tableName, $id) {
        $query = "delete from $tableName where id = :id";
        self::runQuery($query, array('id' => $id));
    }

    public static function insert($tableName, $fields) {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName;
        $query .= '(`' . implode('`,`', array_keys($fields)) . '`) ';
        $query .= 'VALUES (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($fields), '?')) . ')';
        self::runQuery($query, array_values($fields));
    }

    private static function getPartialUpdateStmt() {
        return function($value) {
            return "`$value`" . '=:' . $value;
        };
    }

    public static function update($tableName, $fields, $id) {
        $query = 'UPDATE ' . $tableName . ' SET ';
        $query .= implode(',', array_map(self::getPartialUpdateStmt(), array_keys($fields)));
        $query .= " WHERE id = :id";
        self::runQuery($query, array_merge(array('id' => $id), $fields));
    }

    private static function getRows() {
        return self::$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public static function getSingleResult($query, $bindings = array()) {
        self::runQuery($query, $bindings);
        $rows = self::getRows();
        if (count($rows) > 1) {
            throw new NonUniqueResultException("$query has Multiple results,  bindings = " . implode(",", $bindings));
        } else {
            return $rows ? $rows[0] : null;
        }
    }

    public static function getObject($query, Array $bindings, $className) {
        $obj = null;
        $row = self::getSingleResult($query, $bindings);
        if ($row) {
            $obj = new $className();
            $obj->buildFromDB($row);
        }
        return $obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend you this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD
I guess this will guide you.
Also you can have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1):

I can add something;

Instead of typing everything like this:

```
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getLat() {
    return $this->lat;
}

public function setLat($lat) {
    $this->lat = $lat;
}

public function getLng() {
    return $this->lng;
}

public function setLng($lng) {
    $this->lng = $lng;
}
```

You can simply use two magic methods:

```
public function __get($key) {
    return $this->$key;
}

public function __set($key, $value) {
    $this->$key = $value;
}
```